# Single flavor module based on multi flavor library in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors

I'm working on a multi-flavor `app`. (gradle files below)

It uses a library called `tracker` that follow the same flavors `internal` and `external`

Now for the tricky part, come a new module called `feature`, this one has no flavor but it needs the `tracker` as dependency

**app.gradle:**

```
android {

    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "target"

    productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension "target"
        }

        external {
            dimension "target"
        }
    }
}
```

**tracker.gradle:**

```
android {

    publishNonDefault true

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        debug {
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions 'target'

     productFlavors {
        internal {
            dimension "target"
        }

        external {
            dimension "target"
        }
    }
}
```

**feature.gradle:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    includeCompileClasspath false
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation(
            [...]
            project(':tracker')
    )
}
```

Here are the `errors` when I try to **gradle sync**:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :tracker.

Could not resolve project :tracker.
Required by:
    project :feature
 > Project :feature declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'externalRelease' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :tracker.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :tracker.

Could not resolve project :tracker.
[...]
```

Comment: try this: `implementation project(path: ':tracker', configuration: 'externalRelease')`

Comment: > Project :feature declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'externalRelease' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :tracker.

Comment: read this blog https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My gradle version is 4.4.

In doc, 
[Android developer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) and [Android Plugin DSL Reference](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig:missingDimensionStrategy(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
show that, should add follow code.

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'external'
missingDimensionStrategy 'target'
```

[Android developer link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFD3c.png)

[Android Plugin DSL Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Wtl.png)

but it not work for me. Finally I add follow code in feature.gradle.

```
flavorDimensions 'target'

 productFlavors {
    internal {
        dimension "target"
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not sound like an answer, or?

Comment: The doc show missingDimensionStrategy is the answer. Maybe it can help someone who in different gradle version.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, what I get is that you trying to add the library `tracker` to your `feature` module as dependency. In your `feature.gradle` try the following:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':tracker')
}
```

With Gradle 3.0, there are two new keywords `implementation` and `api`. `compile` keyword is deprecated. You can use `implementation` as default. Use `api` especially when you have a transitive dependencies in your project (Module -> Lib1 -> Lib2), and you need to tell Gradle that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile time.

**Good pictorial explanation:**

Here is a good article telling difference between the `implementation` and `api` keyword: [Implementation Vs Api in Android Gradle plugin 3.0](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa)

**Official doc explanation:**

Here is a brief explanation from the official documentation [Use the new dependency configurations](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations):

- ***Implementation:***

  > When your module configures an implementation dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module does not want to leak the dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the dependency is available to other modules only at runtime. Using this dependency configuration instead of api or compile can result in significant build time improvements because it reduces the amount of projects that the build system needs to recompile. For example, if an implementation dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles only that dependency and the modules that directly depend on it. Most app and test modules should use this configuration.
- ***api:***

  > When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and compile time. This configuration behaves just like compile (which is now deprecated), and you should typically use this only in library modules. That's because, if an api dependency changes its external API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that dependency at compile time. So, having a large number of api dependencies can significantly increase build times. Unless you want to expose a dependency's API to a separate test module, app modules should instead use implementation dependencies.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

For completeness sake, it seems there is a known issue with with gradle 4.1. Using version 4.3 helps. Thanks to Damien.

Comment: changing to api, this is what's happening now:
 
Unable to resolve dependency for ':feature@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :tracker.

Could not resolve project :tracker.
Required by:
    project :feature
 > Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :tracker:
     - externalDebugApiElements
     - internalDebugApiElements
   All of them match the consumer attributes:

Comment: There is a known issue with gradle 4.1, you will be correct with version 4.3

Comment: Aah! I see. Glad you were able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @DamienLocque Is there any link where I can read more about this issue with gradle 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @ramin-eftekhari I managed to make it work

https://github.com/luxsypher/gradle-flavor-dependency

Comment: Your sample doesn't work actually. If you put some classes into :tracker and :feature modules, then :feature module doesn't see classes from :tracker module(

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this in app `build.gradle` `defaultConfig` block:

```
missingDimensionStrategy "internal"
```

Comment: I get an error : **List of requested values cannot be empty**

Comment: Use the following snippet in the debug and release configuration of your app's build.gradle 

`
 debug{
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }
release{
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
        }

`